# How to refer to a variable inside a function with tidy eval after renaming it?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyeval

Is it possible to refer to a variable name after renaming it using tidy evaluation? As an example, I would like to write a function that does the same as the following code but allows to specify the new variable name in a function argument:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  rename(cylinder = cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cylinder) %>% 
  summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
```

However, I am stuck in the `group_by` line (in the code below) because neither `!!varname` nor `{{ varname }}` works as a replacement for the question marks. I assume that `!!varname` does not work because it expands to a character string; and that `{{ varname }}` does not work because no column with the new name exists when the function is called. I don't see a way to use the `glue` syntax either because nothing is being assinged in that line.

```
my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  df %>% 
    rename("{varname}" := cyl) %>% 
    group_by(???) %>%
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running both with {{varname}} seems work

```
my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  df %>% 
    rename({{varname}} := cyl) %>% 
    group_by({{varname}}) %>%
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_rename(mtcars, cylinder)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cylinder mean_mpg
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        4     26.7
2        6     19.7
3        8     15.1
```

Comment: Interesting this works. I thought I had to pass the new variable name as a character string because it is not a "data variable" when it is first evaluated in the line with `rename`. I also did not know `:=` could be used for anything that does not have a string on the left-hand side. Not quite clear from https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Answer (score 3):

In order for your function to work you first have to defuse your custom argument name. For this purpose we could use either `ensym` or `enquo` function for defusing user defined arguments. After that you should use bang bang `(!!)` operator to unquote it.

```
my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  varname <- ensym(varname)
  
  df %>% 
    rename(!!varname := cyl) %>% 
    group_by(!!varname) %>%
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_rename(mtcars, cylinder)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cylinder mean_mpg
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        4     26.7
2        6     19.7
3        8     15.1
```

Here is another way that we use `enquo` function instead of `ensym`:

```
my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  varname <- enquo(varname)
  
  df %>% 
    rename(!!varname := cyl) %>% 
    group_by(!!varname) %>%
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  cylinder mean_mpg
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        4     26.7
2        6     19.7
3        8     15.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the glue syntax, you need `"{{ varname }}" :=`  instead of `"{varname}"`. The simple curly is normal glue syntax, it fetches a string *inside* a variable. The double curly is extended glue syntax, it looks *across* function arguments to see what the user typed. So the correct syntax is:

```
my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  df %>% 
    rename("{{ varname }}" := cyl) %>% 
    group_by({{ varname }}) %>%
    summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg))
}

my_rename(mtcars, cylinder)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   cylinder mean_mpg
#>      <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1        4     26.7
#> 2        6     19.7
#> 3        8     15.1
```

Now let's unpack the behaviour with your original code:

```
my_rename <- function(df, varname) {
  df %>%
    rename("{varname}" := cyl)
}

my_rename(mtcars, cylinder)
#> Error: object 'cylinder' not found
```

The problem here is that `"{varname"}` is essentially doing this:

```
cylinder
#> Error: object 'cylinder' not found
```

Instead of this:

```
rlang::quo(cylinder)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^cylinder
#> env:  global
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I should have mentioned that I was passing the variable name as a string, hence the single curly braces. This code seems to work because `rename` secretly accepts character strings as well as data variables?